# Scrollbar in python with buttons in the window

Tags: tkinter, scrollbar

I have created a new toplevel window in python with buttons in it. But the scrollbar that I have inserted is not working and after some buttons, I am not able to scroll down. Here is the coding

```py
    def myb():
        global bks
        bks=Toplevel()
        bks.geometry("1000x1000")
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(bks)
        scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )
    
        bk1=Button(bks,text= "1.    AND THEN THERE WERE NONE",width=81,height=1,bg="forestgreen",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk1.place(x=0,y=0)
        bk2=Button(bks,text= "2.    THE BIG SLEEP",width=81,height=1,bg="orange",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk2.place(x=0,y=40)
        bk3=Button(bks,text= "3.    GONE GIRL",width=81,height=1,bg="forestgreen",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk3.place(x=0,y=80)
        bk4=Button(bks,text= "4.    THE POSTMAN ALWAYS RINGS TWICE",width=81,height=1,bg="orange",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk4.place(x=0,y=120)
        bk5=Button(bks,text= "5.    IN COLD BLOOD",width=81,height=1,bg="forestgreen",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk5.place(x=0,y=160)
        bk6=Button(bks,text= "6.    THE WOMAN IN WHITE",width=81,height=1,bg="orange",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk6.place(x=0,y=200)
        bk7=Button(bks,text= "7.    ANATOMY OF A MURDER",width=81,height=1,bg="forestgreen",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk7.place(x=0,y=240)
        bk8=Button(bks,text= "8.    TINKER TAILOR SOLDIER SPY",width=81,height=1,bg="orange",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk8.place(x=0,y=280)
        bk9=Button(bks,text= "9.    THE DA VINCI CODE",width=81,height=1,bg="forestgreen",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk9.place(x=0,y=320)
        bk10=Button(bks,text= "10.    THE GIRL WITH THE DRAGON TATTOO",width=81,height=1,bg="orange",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk10.place(x=0,y=360)
        bk11=Button(bks,text= "11.    THE DAUGHTER OF TIME",width=81,height=1,bg="forestgreen",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk11.place(x=0,y=400)
        bk12=Button(bks,text= "12.    REBECCA",width=81,height=1,bg="orange",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk12.place(x=0,y=440)
        bk13=Button(bks,text= "13.    THE INVISIBLE MAN",width=81,height=1,bg="forestgreen",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk13.place(x=0,y=480)
        bk14=Button(bks,text= "14.    MURDER ON THE ORIENT EXPRESS",width=81,height=1,bg="orange",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w")
        bk14.place(x=0,y=520)
```

and 37 more buttons are added. But the Scrollbar is not working. It would be very helpful.
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are hard coding a lot of repeating information, you can probably use a loop to do it. It's good practice.

Comment: I have edited and added the code for scrollbar . thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You can shorten you you code with a `for loop`, for example:

```py
 def myb():
    global bks
    bks=Toplevel()
    bks.geometry("1000x1000")
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(bks)
    scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )
    # This is where all of the text goes, seperate each line with a comma and quotation marks
    ANY_VARIABLE_NAME = ['AND THEN THERE WERE NONE','THE BIG SLEEP'....]
    for i in range(0,len(ANY_VARIABLE_NAME)):
        # if the number is even it's bg='forestgreen' if it is odd it's bg='orange'
        if i % 2 == 0:
            Button(bks,text=(i+1)+ANY_VARIABLE_NAME[i],width=81,height=1,bg="forestgreen",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w").place(x=0,y=i*40)
        else:
            Button(bks,text=(i+1)+ANY_VARIABLE_NAME[i],width=81,height=1,bg="orange",font=("arial",15,"bold"),anchor="w").place(x=0,y=i*40)
    scrollbar.config( command = bks.yview )
```

I  haven't tested this code, but it's just a template you can use to shorten your code

Comment: You have to configure the scrollbar, do this at the end of the code

Comment: The toplevel widget doesn't have a `yview` method.